# Limit output voltage to -1V and 5V

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator

I would like to limit the output of a circuit between -1V and 5V. That is, I want the output of my 'limiter' to be 5V if its input exceeds 5V, and -1 V if it exceeds -1V, and to act like a buffer if my voltage is between -1V and 5V. How can I do this?

Comment: At what current? 1 ΩA, 1 mA, 1 A, 100 A? What power supplies are on the circuit, etc. i.e., You haven't provided enough context for anyone to give a meaningful answer without a lucky guess.

Comment: output = MAX(MIN(input,5),-1)

Comment: Limit it from what? (e.g. limiting -2 to 6V would be different to +/-240V). At what frequency? What impedance is the source? What load are you trying to drive? much info missing.

Comment: Quickest and dirtiest solution I can come up with is a good opamp with  rail-to-rail on both input and output, set it for unity gain and feed it with -1 V Vee and +5 V Vcc. Voilá! Signal is buffered and clamped to -1 to 5 V. @TomCarpenter question is very valid still, what is the range of input signals?

Answer (score 0):

Connect your output through a fuse, and then shunt the fused
output to ground through a 5.1V zener diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkSYtT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the fuse is correctly sized, your 'circuit' won't be damaged,
and the 5.1V zener (about 5% tolerance) will limit the new output
within half a volt of your specified (+) limit,and (-.3 to -.8)V, 
within your (-) limit.

It may waste power, require heat sinking, limit frequency response,
decalibrate your output, etc.

More elaborate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftEU5G.png)</sup>